# PHP form with multiple questions, each with several options that output a text response based off selections

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to create a simple PHP script that creates canned responses for different customer issues. I'd like a few different questions that can accept multiple answers via checkboxes or a dropdown. FYI I'm a beginner, so excuse my ignorance. I tried it with a switch statement, but ran into issues with needing to use more than one variable. Then I tried multiple elseif statements but couldn't get anything to evaluate past the first question. Each checkbox would essentially have a little excerpt that echos when it is the one selected. So with three questions, the output would actually create three snippets that all display in order. This way I could simply copy and paste the output. If anybody could help me out or even just point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. I've been doing a lot of googling and haven't gotten what I need.

Here is some unfinished test code I was messing with to see if I could figure it out. When I try this, only the part for colors works. The next part for food always goes to the evaluates as the 'else' portion, regardless of what's actually selected.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $color_val = $_POST['Color'];
   $food_val = $_POST['food'];
   $drink_val = $_POST['drink'];


   if ($color_val == "Red") {
       echo "Red blurb";
       echo "<br>";
   }
   elseif ($color_val == "Green") {
       echo "Green blurb turb";
       echo "<br>";
   }
   elseif ($color_val == "Blue"){
       echo "True blue homey";
       echo "<br>";
   }

   else {
       echo "none selected";
       echo "<br>";
   }

   if ($food_val == "Wings") {
       echo "wingy wings";
       echo "<br>";
   }
   elseif ($food_val == "Pizza") {
       echo "pizza, pizza";
       echo "<br>";
   }
   else {
       echo "nothing selected";
       "<br>";
   }
?>


form action="#" method="post">
   <select name="Color">
       <option value="Red">Red</option>
       <option value="Green">Green</option>
       <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
   </select>
   <select name="food">
       <option value="wings">Wings</option>
       <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
   </select>
   <select name = "drink">
       <option value="soda">Soda</option>
       <option value="water">Water</option>
       <option value="beer">Beer</option>
   </select>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
```

Comment: did you select options from all the dropdowns then submitted the form ?

Comment: Yes I did. The first output corresponded with the color selected, but the next line just says "nothing selected" regardless of what food item is actually selected when the form is submitted.

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)` and give me the result.

Comment: @ths   This is the result. All those values are correspond correctly with what was selected upon submitting the form too.                                                      Green blurb turb
nothing selectedarray(4) { ["Color"]=> string(5) "Green" ["food"]=> string(5) "pizza" ["drink"]=> string(5) "water" ["submit"]=> string(19) "Get Selected Values" }

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need to either handle the variation in the values to the strings that you are comparing to **or** be consistent with the values that you are using in the html and your tests in php.

```
$str = "Wings";
$test = "wings";
if ($str == $test){ //false
    echo "$str == $test";
}
if (strtolower($str) == $test){  //true
    echo "$str == $test";
}
```

Comment: Wings != wings,  Php is case sensitive.

Comment: Oops! I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for noticing.

Comment: On an unrelated issue, I would recommend that you place an default option at the top of each select.
<option value="" Hidden>Select</option>

Comment: I actually had just started to do that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with case sensitivity, `Wings != wings` notice the uppercase 'W' is different from 'w'. So, we need to convert the strings to either uppercase or lowercase.

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   // convert the strings to lowercase
   $color_val = strtolower($_POST['Color']);
   $food_val = strtolower($_POST['food']);
   $drink_val = strtolower($_POST['drink']);


   if ($color_val == "red") {
       echo "Red blurb";
       echo "<br>";
   }
   elseif ($color_val == "green") {
       echo "Green blurb turb";
       echo "<br>";
   }
   elseif ($color_val == "blue"){
       echo "True blue homey";
       echo "<br>";
   }

   else {
       echo "none selected";
       echo "<br>";
   }

   if ($food_val == "wings") {
       echo "wingy wings";
       echo "<br>";
   }
   elseif ($food_val == "pizza") {
       echo "pizza, pizza";
       echo "<br>";
   }
   else {
       echo "nothing selected";
       "<br>";
   }
```

Comment: Yes, Jon Le pointed that out. Silly me. It's working now though. Thanks for the help!